# Not Awaitable Type error in my async MSTest Test

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, async-await

this is the first time using async in .NET so I'm totally lost here.

Also I'm trying to use the HttpClient in a unit test to make some calls to my WCF web service.  I'm not doing something right because I get "HttpResponseMessage" is not awaitable below.  Also it's not recognizing "ReadAsAsync".

I'm not even sure I am doing this right yet

```
       [TestMethod]
        public async Task GetTest_RestEndpoint_ListOFInventoryReturnedIsNotNull()
        {
            // Arrange
                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost/Inventory/");
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                    // HTTP GET
                    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("?memberid=323&count=12&pagenumber=1&sortorder=2&eventId=1211");
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        InventoryResponse inventoryResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<InventoryResponse>();
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}\t${1}\t{2}", inventoryPostResponse.EventID);
                    }
...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Also it's not recognizing "ReadAsAsync".

Here's your primary problem. The [`ReadAsAsync<T>()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh944541%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) extension method is part of the [`HttpContentExtensions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpcontentextensions%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) class, which is located in the `System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll` assembly. Make sure you've added a reference to `System.Net.Http.Formatting` to your project.

Comment: updated my csproj from 4.0 to 4.5 then referenced the 4.5 version of  http.formatting, resolved it now